# How to replace a letter from a text file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I have a text file named, `file.txt` it contains,**

```
i love bats and batch
```

**i like to replace letter `b` with `c`**

**expected output in a separate file, `output.txt` ,**

```
i love cats and catch
```

**Important note :** it have to only replace only the letter, not to replace whole word..

**I am using the code,**

```
set /p "input=<file.txt"
set b=c >>output.txt
```

But, i am getting blank in `output.txt` i accept am noob to batch. How to fix my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `set b=c` assigns the value `c` to a variable `b`, which is not what you need.

The following code does what you want, given the input file only contains a single line:

```cmd
rem // Read (first) line from input file into variable:
set /P input=<"file.txt"
rem // Replace `b` with `c` and write result to output file:
echo/%input:b=c%>>"output.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a line contains not more than 8 letters `b`:

```sh
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=b tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set new=%%a
    if not ""=="%%b" set new=!new!c%%b
    if not ""=="%%c" set new=!new!c%%c
    if not ""=="%%d" set new=!new!c%%d
    if not ""=="%%e" set new=!new!c%%e
    if not ""=="%%f" set new=!new!c%%f
    if not ""=="%%g" set new=!new!c%%g
    if not ""=="%%h" set new=!new!c%%h
    if not ""=="%%i" set new=!new!c%%i
    echo !new!>>output.txt
)
```

if there is more than 8 `b` symbols the rest of line after 9th symbol will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

@aschipfl's Method can be adapted to Replace strings in the Entire File like So:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
set /P "input=Drop your file here: >"
Set /p Replace=[String to replace:]
Set /p With=[Replacement text:]
FOR /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%l IN (%input%) DO (
rem // Read (lines by token) from input file into variable:
set output=%%l
rem // Replace `b` with `c` and write result to output file:
CALL :write
)

START notepad.exe "output.txt"
pause

REM I had to cheat and use a variable to Get the Output substituion to Expand properly.

:write
set "Substitute=!output:%Replace%=%With%!"
echo/%Substitute%>>"output.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

*** Notes ***

```
- The filename input method is not Suitbale file pathways with Spaces.
- There are limits to the number of tokens, and therefor the number of lines this method will work for is limited.
- Lack of input validation means it's only suitable for plain text, Not code.
```